# What is min # of pairs req’d for sufficient confidence from a given pairwise ranking algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

**What is min # of pairs req’d for sufficient confidence from a given pairwise ranking algorithm?**

Note: I'm a little rusty and don't have a comp sci background, just an undergrad math deg about 10 yrs ago, which I don't use in my day job much. But I have an issue which I could really use help understanding. If you have any insights, they'd be greatly appreciated ;). Here we go....

**Assumptions:**

- N users
- K items Aj, j=1,…,K to be ranked
- Each of the N users has defined an ordinal ranking of the K items in advance, that is, for each user i, there is a ranking R(i) = (A1,…,AK), where Aj represents one of the K items and Aj < A(j+1).
- These rankings are stored in tables, i.e. we know these rankings in advance.
- Call the *aggregate ranking of item j* simply the average of its rank for each of the N users. So for example if N=2, and the two users have an item ranked 4th and 8th respectively, this item’s aggregate rank is (4+8)/2=6th. This then defines an *aggregate ranking of K items*. This is what we want to predict with our chosen algorithm.
- Each of the N users will be asked to compare X pairs.
- Let’s assume we use a very strong pairwise ranking algorithm (pick your favourite) to select what pairs to show each of the users (i.e. it can dynamically select pairs to display to users that take advantage of properties of transitivity)
- Assume that when the algorithm is run for any particular user, it simply consults the table of predefined rankings for this user and makes the selection.
- For any resulting *predicted ranking* output by the algorithm, we can define some measure of the error, or difference between the predicted ranking and the actual aggregated ranking. Let’s call this *rank error* (e.g. perhaps the average deviation in the location for items ranked would suffice).

**Problem: How many pairs do we need the algorithm to look up for each user to minimize this rank error?**

To get this into familiar confidence interval terminology, let’s give this problem some numbers (these are actually the numbers I care about but became interested in the problem in general).

- N=10 users
- K=15 items
- We want to predict the aggregated ranking of the top 3 ranked items only
- Now only have one parameter, X = number of pairs algorithm queries for comparisons

To do this, we could simply run the algorithm a very large number of times (10^whatever, i.e. a Monte Carlo simulation) and assign a value of 1 for each time the algorithm's predicted top 3 equals the actual top 3, and a value of 0 otherwise. To get different trial simulations we could vary the input (i.e. if the algo will produce the same result) randomly. The question then would be, what is the frequency of 1s in running this simulation? This can be our measure of confidence. So then the question becomes, for a given level of confidence, say 90%, what is the value of X?

One thing that seems intuitively clear is that the more dispersion there is between the different user's rankings, the less impact increasing N (# of users) would have on confidence levels. That is, if you imagine that all N have exactly the same ranking (i.e. zero dispersion), you'd only need to present them with at most the K*(K-1)/2 unique pairs to get a perfect ranking with 100% confidence. On the otherhand, if you assume that N=K! where each of the N users has each of the unique possible rankings, you would converge to 100% confidence very very slowly. Interestingly, in fact, you could argue that if the goal was to select a top 3 in this case, you'd be no better off than picking 3 at random in which case, you need zero users input! Thought that was interesting.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  (Beware that averaging rankings is a slightly dubious.)  I'm quite confused by your question.  You talk about repeatedly running the algorithm, but I don't see any randomness in your algorithm: if you run it twice it seems like you'll get the same answer.  Also, this question is very long and there are a lot of details to absorb, so I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Any chance you can abstract things out?  Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval?

Comment: I've tried to be as concise as possible, sorry if its confusing.... As far as the monte carlo part; if the algorithm is deterministic, you can randomize the inputs i.e. create random rankings for the N users.

Comment: Also, averaging rankings is what I am looking for. Think of something like MVP voting for a major sport. Or the points system for finishes in F1 races...same thing. They just don't divide by number of votes or races ;-)

Comment: You haven't defined "predicted ranking."  And I agree with @D.W. that your definition of "aggregate ranking" is going to give very odd, skewed results in real world applications.

Comment: If every ranking for every user is stored in a table and known to you in advance, what are you attempting to "predict"?  Just run the calculation against the known tables.

Comment: Thought 'predicted ranking' is clear. Let's say you have a ranking of 10 different restaurants on your block. If I wanted to discover it via a pairwise exercise, I could (a) ask you to review all 45 combinations to get your ranking, or (b) I could do this in far fewer steps, but there may be discrepancies (i.e. error). Option (b) predicts what the actual ranking is.

Comment: If you vote for the top 10 players in baseball, where 1st place receives 10 votes, 2nd place receives 9 votes, etc. and then add these votes up between you and your friends, the resulting ranking, as determined by the sum of votes is precisely an aggregated ranking.

Comment: We are testing the accuracy of an algorithm. Consider these tables "test" data. We know what we should get, i.e. an aggregated ranking result with low error. So we test it. If we have confidence that it produces the result we want on test data, then we can apply it to cases where the rankings are unknown....